# Do ideals in regular local rings contain prime ideals of smaller heights?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a regular local ring. If $I$ is ideal of height strictly larger than $h$, does $I$ contain a height $h$ prime ideal?

I’m particularly interested in the case of mixed characteristic complete rings.

Comment: Do you have an example where this fails if R is not regular?

Comment: And am I right to think that if I were prime, this would follow from the definition of height?

Comment: Might not need regular for all I know, and yes, for primes this would be just from the definition.

Comment: For a counterexample when $R$ is not regular, I guess you could take $R = k[x,y,z]/xy$ and $I = (z)$ which has height 1 but isn't prime.  Then the height-0  / minimal primes are $(x)$ and $(y)$, neither of which contains $I$.